# Highlighting a cell while touching iphone(giving a glowing effect just like touching a button)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This may be a simple question but i cant find a solution.i'm using a table view.i want to give a highlight option when user selects that cell.highlight means giving a glowing effect for the cell(just like highlighting  a button while touching.Is this possible.Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: batter to add  custom button to entire cell

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in several ways:

1. Programmatically when customizing your `UITableViewCell` by setting appropriate value of `selectionStyle` (UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue, UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray or UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone)

   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
2. In Interface Builder (if you load your cell from .xib file):

   In the `Attribute Inspector` set property `Selection` : `blue, gray, none`

Comment: ,i want a glowing effect for cells just like we giving for buttons

Comment: Its not possible, but if you want it really then create an image which gives you feel for highlight and set it as background image of that cell.